# What are examples where the quantum discord is achieved by a non-projective POVM?

Tags: measurement, povm, mutual-information, quantum-discord

Consider the (asymmetric) quantum discord, defined as (borrowing notation from Eq. 4.13c of [Zurek's review](https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.09019)):
$$\mathcal D(\mathcal S:\mathcal A) = I(\mathcal S:\mathcal A) - \chi(\rho_{\mathcal A}),$$
where
$$\chi(\rho_{\cal A}) \equiv \max_{\{\boldsymbol\pi_k\}}(H(\rho_{\mathcal A}) - \sum_k p_k H(\mathcal A|\boldsymbol\pi_k)).$$
Here we're considering bipartite states $\rho\equiv\rho_{\mathcal S\mathcal A}$, denoting with $I(\mathcal S:\mathcal A)$ the standard quantum mutual information, and the maximum is taken with respect to all possible POVMs $\{\boldsymbol\pi_k\}_k$, so that $\sum_k \boldsymbol\pi_k=I$ and $\boldsymbol\pi_k\ge0$.
The outcome probabilities read $p_k\equiv \operatorname{tr}(\boldsymbol\pi_k \rho_{\cal SA})$, and $H(\mathcal A|\boldsymbol\pi_k)$ is the entropy of $\mathcal A$ conditioned on having measured $\mathcal S$ and found the $k$-th outcome, meaning that
$H(\mathcal A|\boldsymbol\pi_k)$ is the (von Neumann) entropy of the state $\rho_k\equiv \operatorname{tr}_{\cal S}(\boldsymbol\pi_k\rho_{\cal SA})/p_k$.

It is mentioned in the above review (just above (4.12c)) that there are situations where the maximum in the definition of $\chi(\rho_{\cal A})$, or equivalently, the accessible mutual information, is achieved with *non-projective POVMs*. I'm looking for explicit "simple" examples of this being the case.

In ([Modi et al. 2011](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.6238)) the authors mention (section I.3, page 11) that the discord is always optimized by rank-1 extremal POVMs.
Most topical reviews ([Modi et al. 2011](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.6238), [Modi 2013](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.7676), [Bera et al. 2017](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.10542)) mention the fact that the discord is in general achieved with non-projective POVMs, but I'm failing to actually extract an explicit simple examples from the provided citations.
Going through the relevant references given in (Modi 2011), I see that ([Chen et al. 2011](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.0181)) work out the discord for two-qubit X states. However, if I understand correctly, this is still a numerical result. ([Galve et al. 2011](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.2005)) show that for rank-2 states PVMs are sufficient, but only show numerically that POVMs are more generally needed. ([Shi et al. 2011](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.2005)) also analyze the discord of X-states and show that non-projective PVMs are needed, but also in this case I don't know how to extract an explicit example of such a state and associated POVM.

Is there any analytical example of a state where the discord/accessible information (be it the asymmetric or symmetric one) is achieved with non-projective measurements?

Comment: Zwolak and Zurek expressely state that this thesis https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0611157 proves that rank 1 projectors minimize discord. A few other papers do as well, though it may be it just minimized it withing the framework they are exploring.

Comment: @GaussStrife I actually don't see any mention of discord or accessible information in that paper. Where do you mean exactly? Also, I know that by convexity arguments we can prove that the discord is always minimized by rank-1 extremal POVMs. This is also mentioned in the linked reviews. That's not the same as saying it's minimized by rank-1 projectors (meaning projective measurements I suppose). Is that what you meant?

Comment: Sorry, this was the thesis https://arxiv.org/pdf/0807.4490.pdf. Yes I am aware that the general proof is with POVM's, which that thesis shows. The paper where Zurek states rank 1 projectors minimize it is this one https://www.nature.com/articles/srep01729.